# Ajax request not work rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to hit the database at the exit of a field without reloading the form using Ajax.  The controller must do some process on the data obtained from the database and respond to the view.  The user will then continue with the input.

I am missing something and just can't see what is wrong. I have the same piece of code working in a Rails 3.2 application without a problem.  In Rails 3.2 the request goes to the `check_matricula` method, but in Rails 4, it goes to the `show` action.

The following code is not working in my Rails 4 app:

**Gemfile**

`gem 'responders', '~> 2.0'`

**View**

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :matricula, { "data-remote" => true, "data-url" => "/liquidaciones_de_viajes/check_matricula", "data-type" => :json, :size => 10 } %>
    <span id="check_matricula">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
class LiquidacionesDeViajesController < ApplicationController
        respond_to :html, :json

  def check_matricula
    @matricula = Matricula.find_by_codigo(params[:liquidacion_de_viajes][:matricula])

    # ... some process that result in matricula_ok true or false ...

    if matricula_ok
      respond_with(@matricula.empresa.razon_social)
    else
      respond_with(nil)
    end
  end
end
```

**assets/javascripts/check_matricula.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#liquidacion_de_viajes_matricula").bind('ajax:success', function(evt, data, status, xhr) {
        if (data !== null) {
            $('#razon_social').html(data.razon_social);
            $('#check_matricula').html('');
        } else {
            $('#check_matricula').html('Error de matricula');
            $('#razon_social').empty();
        }
    });

    $("#liquidacion_de_viajes_matricula").live('ajax:before', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            return false;
        }
    });

    $("#liquidacion_de_viajes_matricula").focus(function() {
        $('#check_matricula').empty();
        $('#razon_social').empty();
    });
});
```

I see in console a GET is there but I did a POST in the route:

```
Started GET "/liquidaciones_de_viajes/check_matricula?liquidacion_de_viajes%5Bmatricula%5D=5‌​555" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-30 15:00:50 -0300
Processing by LiquidacionesDeViajesController#show as JSON
Parameters: {"liquidacion_de_viajes"=>{"matricula"=>"5555"}, "id"=>"check_matricula"}
```

Comment: The first step I could suggest you in debugging is to inspect requests & responses. Navigate to your form page. If you're using Chrome, right click on the page and click Inspect. In the Developer tools that will pop up, click "Network" tab. Then try typing on your `f.text_field :matricula`. You should then notice those new requests will appear in that Developer tools pane. Click that one request in the developer tools, and a new pane will appear. On that side pane, click "Response". Then inspect if the response is correct. If this didn't help, the next step is to debug the JS or controller.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your response in Json

```
  def check_matricula
      @matricula = Matricula.find_by_codigo(params[:liquidacion_de_viajes][:matricula])

  ... some process that result in matricula_ok true or false ...

       if matricula_ok
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.json{
            render :json => @matricula.empresa.razon_social.to_json
          }
      end

      else
          respond_with(nil)
      end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to specify the `check_matricula` route for your contoller:

```
resources : liquidaciones_de_viajes do
  collection do
    post `check_matricula`
  end
end
```

Without this route, Rails assumes that `check_matricula` is the `:id` portion of the `show` route.

To send the requests to the URL via `POST`, add the `data-method: :post` option to your `text_field`, like so:

```
<%= f.text_field :matricula, { data-remote: true, data-url: "/liquidaciones_de_viajes/check_matricula", data-type: :json, data-method: :post, size: 10 } %>
```

Comment: I did the route, but the problem persist; the show method is invoked and rails try to load an obviously inexistent record from the table. I see in console a GET is there but I did a POST in the route:


Started GET "/liquidaciones_de_viajes/check_matricula?liquidacion_de_viajes%5Bmatricula%5D=5555" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-30 15:00:50 -0300
Processing by LiquidacionesDeViajesController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"liquidacion_de_viajes"=>{"matricula"=>"5555"}, "id"=>"check_matricula"}

Comment: @RaulLopez I updated the answer, and added the POST method to the `text_field`.  That will make the request go to `POST check_matricula` instead of `GET show`.

Comment: lUsing same code and GET in rails 3.2 is ok but not in 4.2:
rails 3.2.13
Started GET "/liquidaciones_de_viajes/check_matricula?liquidacion_de_viajes%5Bmatricula%5D=5555" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-30 16:27:58 -0300
Processing by LiquidacionesDeViajesController#check_matricula as JSON   

rails 4.2.3
Started GET "/liquidaciones_de_viajes/check_matricula?liquidacion_de_viajes%5Bmatricula%5D=6666" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-30 16:32:05 -0300
Processing by LiquidacionesDeViajesController#show as JSON